# JQUERY if not hover

Tags: jquery

Mouseenter of DIV A sets DIV B to show().  What I want is on mouseleave of DIV A if they are **not** hovering over DIV B, hide DIV B.  But, on mouseleave of DIV A if they are hovering over DIV B keep showing DIV B.

```
$('#DIVA').mouseenter(function() {
        $('#DIVB').show();  
    }).mouseleave(function() {      
        //if DIVB not hovering
            $('#DIVB').hide();
        //end if
    });
```

Comment: Can you show the markup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be as simple as just using [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

http://jsbin.com/ojipu/2

...but that depends on what the markup looks like.

Comment: It relies on Div B using the same space as Div A, what if they have distance between them?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would leave Div A and still know to show Div B if they didn't overlap.

Comment: I had the same problem. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645551/how-to-interrupt-a-hovers-handlerout

Answer (score 16):

Could you add a class to `#DIVB` on hover then check for it on `mouseleave` for `#DIVA`?

```
$('#DIVB').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
})

$('#DIVA').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#DIVB').show();  
}).mouseleave(function() {      
    if(!$('#DIVB').hasClass('active')){
        $('#DIVB').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I actually used bits of both of your solutions.  Thank you both!